# Wordpress plugin for syntax highlighting

Tags: wordpress, plugin

What nice syntax highlighting plugins do people use for Wordpress?

Comment: This would be better asked here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500/wordpress-answers

Comment: This stackexchange proliferation of sites is quite crazy :) You never know where to post. Thanks for the suggestion though. I found a post for what I wanted there.

Answer (score 2):

I use [SyntaxHighlighter Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter-plus/). Hasn't been updated in some time, but still works. Supports a decent variety of languages, more than enough for my needs. Based on the [SyntaxHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) package by Alex Gorbatchev.

Answer (score 1):

[WP-Syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/)